# How get line function taking on charecter and object

Tags: c++

I saw the use of `getline()` in my project, but its used as like below, is the function are defined in different library with different parameter type

```
std::string str;
 getline(cin, str);
```

and

```
char title[256]
std::cin.getline (title,256);
```

How `getline()` is working on both object as `argument` and `charecter array` as argument also.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You want an explanation of how those two functions work?

Comment: Those are two different functions.

Comment: @Scheff, it has nothing common with polymirphism

Comment: @YurySchkatula Because, `std::getline()` and `cin.getline()` are not in the same scope? Yepp. I've to admit you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Those are different functions, they happen to have the same name.

The first one is `std::getline`, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
This one takes an `istream` object and a `string` object as arguments, and it reads characters from the stream, store it inside the string.

The second one is `std::basic_istream::getline`, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline
This one is a member method on an `istream` object. It takes an char array argument, and extracts characters from it and put into the stream. It extracts as many characters as you specify as the second argument, or until end of the char array.